# SwiftUI/Swift code for changing item values in an immutable struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

just wanted someone to review my code and perhaps simplify it a bit. Everything is working as expected for the moment but it seems too much code for what i'm trying to achieve. Especially the function "toggleItems". It just feels ... not right.

GOAL: The idea is that i'm having a list with a fixed set of items. When selecting an item, an indicator needs to light up which indicates which list item was pressed last (active state). All other list items need to be deactivated at that point. At first i was using variables in my data model (struct) but wanted to avoid that they could be changed from without the struct so i tried using an immutable struct here (credits to "Swiftful Thinking" on Youtube)

SoundModel:

```swift
struct SoundModel: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let displayName: String
    let isActive: Bool
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, name: String, displayName: String, isActive: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.isActive = isActive
    }
    
    func updateActiveStateToFalse() -> SoundModel {
        return SoundModel(id: id, name: name, displayName: displayName, isActive: false)
    }
    
    func updateActiveStateToTrue() -> SoundModel {
        return SoundModel(id: id, name: name, displayName: displayName, isActive: true)
    }
}
```

the SoundViewViewModel:

```swift
class SoundViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sounds: [SoundModel] = []
    
    init() {
        sounds.append(contentsOf: [
            SoundModel(name: "alarm1", displayName: "Alarm 1", isActive: true),
            SoundModel(name: "alarm2", displayName: "Alarm 2", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "alarm3", displayName: "Alarm 3", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "bird1", displayName: "Bird", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "carhorn1", displayName: "Carhorn", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "fireAlarm1", displayName: "Fire Alarm", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "mellow", displayName: "Mellow", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "meltdown1", displayName: "Meltdown", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "schoolbel1", displayName: "Schoolbel", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "siren1", displayName: "Siren", isActive: false),
            SoundModel(name: "ufo1", displayName: "Ufo", isActive: false),
        ]
        )
    }

    func toggleItems(soundItem: SoundModel) {

        if let index = sounds.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == soundItem.id } ) {
            if !soundItem.isActive {
                sounds[index] = soundItem.updateActiveStateToTrue()
                
            }
        }
        
        for sound in sounds {
            if let index = sounds.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == sound.id && $0.id != soundItem.id }) {
                if sounds[index].isActive {
                    sounds[index] = sound.updateActiveStateToFalse()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my SoundView:

```swift
struct SoundsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var theme: ThemeManager
    
    //var soundManager = SoundManager()
    @StateObject var soundViewVM = SoundViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(soundViewVM.sounds) { sound in
                Button {
                    //soundManager.playSound(name: sound.name)
                    soundViewVM.toggleItems(soundItem: sound)

                } label: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                        Text(sound.displayName)
                        Spacer()
                        sound.isActive ? Circle().frame(width: 10).foregroundColor(theme.lightColor) : nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.elliptical)
        .navigationTitle {
            HStack {
                Text("Sounds")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm weird, let me review it for a sec. About the listStyle and navigationTitle, I'm using it in a watchOS app.

Comment: It works here. I guess the issue is within the toggleItems(soundItem: SoundModel) function as I had the same behavior as well when I started, but like it's written here it should function correctly.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. don't know how I copied that code wrong :/

sounds[index] = sound.updateActiveStateToFalse() does the trick (I already have the sound object from the for loop). I will edit again in my code. Now, looking at that function, should it be the right way to do it ? getting the indexes. Or is there a more simple manner ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toggleItems()` function can be simplified to

```
func toggleItems(soundItem: SoundModel) {
    
    for (index, sound) in sounds.enumerated() {
        if sound.id == soundItem.id {
            sounds[index] = sound.updateActiveStateToTrue()
        } else {
            sounds[index] = sound.updateActiveStateToFalse()
        }
    }
}
```

with one simple loop instead of two loops in your code (where the second one is essentially a nested loop).

But what I would really do is to store the information about the currently selected sound in the view model, instead of having an `isActive` property in `SoundModel`:

```
class SoundViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sounds: [SoundModel]
    @Published var activeSoundId : SoundModel.ID?
    
    init() {
        let allSounds = [ ... ]
        sounds = allSounds
        activeSoundId = allSounds.first?.id
    }
}
```

Then making a sound “active” becomes as simple as

```
soundViewVM.activeSoundId = sound.id
```

without the need to traverse the array and updating each entry with a new (active or inactive) one. This makes the `toggleItems()` method obsolete, and the view code becomes

```
struct SoundsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var soundViewVM = SoundViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(soundViewVM.sounds) { sound in
                Button {
                    soundViewVM.activeSoundId = sound.id
                } label: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2) {
                        Text(sound.displayName)
                        Spacer()
                        if sound.id == soundViewVM.activeSoundId {
                            Circle().frame(width: 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `isActive` property and the `updateActiveStateToFalse/True()` methods in `SoundModel` are no longer needed. Instead of converting the UUIDs to strings one can use the `UUID` directly for identification:

```
struct SoundModel: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let displayName: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, displayName: String, isActive: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow very nice  approach. Going to look into it in depth an try to use this approach more.